# Im trying load data by receive this error, anyway to fix this?

Tags: csv, primary-key

My query is
mysql> Load DATA INFILE '/home/codio/workspace/FleetMaintenanceRecords.csv' INTO Table PartsMaintenance FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' Lines Terminated BY '\n' Ignore 1 Rows;
I receive this error
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '15241383936' for key 'PRIMARY'

I tried to load a csv file but got a error code about my primary key, how can I fix this?